# Cannot get AngularDart filtering working

Tags: filter, dart, angular-dart

I am trying to apply the Angular Dart tutorial (Recipe Book app) to a real project of mine. Everything is working fine, except the basic filtering on a name. The code is almost identical to the tutorial:

```dart
<div id="filters">
<div>
  <label for="name-filter">Filter clients by name</label>
  <input id="name-filter" type="text" 
         ng-model="ctrl.nameFilterString">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Clear Filters" ng-click="ctrl.clearFilters()">
```

```dart
<ul class="list-group"> 
<li class="list-group-item"
    ng-repeat="client in ctrl.clients | filter:{en_name:ctrl.nameFilterString}"
    ng-click="ctrl.selectClient(client)">
    {{ client.en_name }} ({{ client.acronym }})
</li>
```

But the list is not displayed at all. If I remove `| filter:{en_name:ctrl.nameFilterString}`, the list of clients is properly displayed. `orderBy: 'en_name'` works fine too. The string is defined in my controller, and the "clearFilters()" function works fine.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What is `ctrl.clients`? A map, a class, ...? What value has `ctrl.nameFilterString`?

Comment: clients is a list defined in my controller: `List<Client> clients = [];`, it is populated through a backend RESTful API. Same for the string, it is a property on the controller: `String nameFilterString = "";`.

Comment: I built an example similar to yours and it works fine.

Comment: Can you add `{{ctrl.nameFilterString}}` somewhere to verify what value it returns? (and post the result here)

Comment: I added it right before the `<ul>` element, and it properly displays whatever I type in the filter input. It is cleared when I clear the filtering string.

Comment: What Angular version are you using? I used 0.9.10. The easiest way to find the version is to expand the `packages` directory in your package (in DartEditor).

Comment: When I switch back to 0.9.9 it stops working. Updating to 0.9.10 fixes it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with the used Angular version 0.9.9.

I tried it with 0.9.10 and it works.
Downgrading to 0.9.9 resulted `ng-repeate` producing no output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and is being tracked at https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/800

Comment: But it works in 0.9.10, how can it be an open bug? I think bug #800 is something different.

Comment: Ah, you are right.  I missed that ctrl.nameFilterString was a string and not a filter function.